# How to move mat-icon-button focus effect

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this button

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="black" style="height: 21px; bottom: 8px;" *ngIf="!transaction.HasMatch" (click)="matchPayable($event, transaction)">
   <mat-icon style="line-height: 20px;">playlist_add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

The problem is, that when I click on the button, the focus is not exactly around the icon as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrWaF.png).
So the focus needs to be moved downwards, but I don't know how.
It would be an alternative to remove the focus effect completely. Also I don’t know how to achieve this.

Comment: You screenshot is really hard to understand. Could you replace it? Even better would be to provide a stackblitz example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix was the following:

```
        <button mat-icon-button color="black" style="height: 25px; width: 25px; left: 3px;" *ngIf="!transaction.HasMatch" (click)="matchPayable($event, transaction)">
            <mat-icon style="line-height: 10px;" >playlist_add</mat-icon>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying customized CSS to the `::ng-deep` pseudo-element will allow you to change the focus position of a `mat-icon-button.` To move the focus impact lower in your situation, paste the CSS code shown below:

```
::ng-deep .mat-icon-button:focus:not(.cdk-focused) {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  outline: none;
}

::ng-deep .mat-icon-button:focus:not(.cdk-focused)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px; /* adjust this value to move the focus effect downwards */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ripple 1s linear;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

The `mat-icon-button` element will receive a custom focus effect from this code that shifts the emphasis 5 pixels to the right. The `bottom` value can be changed to alter the focal effect up or down as necessary.

You should be aware that `::ng-deep` is a deprecated pseudo-selector and that a separate method should be used to apply styles to child components.